# Managing MongoDB database connection Based on User Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

Good Morning Everyone.
for my project I'm Using mongo Atlas DB + Nodejs + express js
Currently let say I have one customer and all his users(managed with local-passport-js) and data are managed inside one DB in my cluster.
I'm Interested managing my project a step forward and create multiple DB's one for each costumer .
every costumer will have a different DB managing his users and data.

this is my current connection to the Db:

```
const MongoUrl = `mongodb+srv://*myuser**:${process.env.password}@testdb.9unfgh9.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

mongoose.connect(MongoUrl, 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(()=> {
    console.log('DB Connection, Successful')
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error connecting DB')
    console.log(err)
})
```

How can I Create "Global" User Collection and determine which DB the user Associate to and load it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `dotenv` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Create a .env corresponding to your development or production environment

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://<your-user-name>:<your-password>@whatever.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

and code like this

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import 'dotenv/config';

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```